# DNS records: best parameters with a / cname for a domain with and without www

Tags: dns, cname

What is the best between those DNS records for a domain name (with and without www) hosted at host1 (my registrar) for the emails and at host2 for its website ?

```
-       MX   mx.host1
-       MX   mx-cache.host1 
-       A    (host2 IP)     
- www   A    (same host2 IP)
```

or

```
-       MX    mx.host1  
-       MX    mx-cache.host1    
-       A     (host2 IP)        
-  www  CNAME domain
```

Did I miss something? Actually the URL without www displays the homepage, but when I add the www I have an error, after more than 40 seconds...

A nslookup for the domain with and without www displays the host2 IP, which seems to be OK.

Maybe the problem comes from the host2 parameters, not from the DNS parameters at my registrar?

A huge thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is definitly the right one!

Are you sure your problem is not due to the dns not yet being refreshed?

Are you hosting your own DNS or is it at you registrar?

for the latter, you sometime have to wait up to 48H for it to refresh.

what exactly is the output of your NSLOOKUP?

Comment: Thank you @Jmorvan for your answer. 

nslookup URL
Server:  IP host1
Address: IP host1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name: www.URL
Address: IP host2

I'm almost convinced that the issue is due to a misconfiguration at host2, not with my DNS records. But it's out of my hands.

Comment: Well sorry I couldnt help more! I guess you'll have to sort this out with your registrar or whoever handles your record. cheers